# Did you forget to register or load this tag in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I tried to insert image of wine in wine_list .html and I get this error that

**Invalid block tag on line 21: 'static'reviews\images\download(1).jpg'', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?**

Here is the code for wine_list

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block title %}
    <h2>Wine list</h2>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
    {% if wine_list %}
    {% load static %}

    <div>
        {% for wine in wine_list %}
        <div>
            <h4><a href="{% url 'reviews:wine_detail' wine.id %}">
            {{ wine.name }}
                   {
    <div class="w-col w-col-3 download">
              <a href="#"><img class="img-rounded" 
                src="{% static'reviews\images\download(1).jpg'%}" alt="CEe"></a>
            </div>
        }
            </a></h4>
            <h5>{{ wine.review_set.count }} reviews</h5>
            <h5> average rating</h5>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% else %}
        <p>No wines are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
```

here is also the  code for views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .models import Review, Wine
from .forms import ReviewForm
import datetime

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def review_list(request):
    latest_review_list = Review.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:9]
    context = {'latest_review_list': latest_review_list}
    return render(request, 'reviews/review_list.html', context)


def review_detail(request, review_id):
    review = get_object_or_404(Review, pk=review_id)
    return render(request, 'reviews/review_detail.html', {'review': review})


def wine_list(request):
    wine_list = Wine.objects.order_by('-name')
    context = {'wine_list': wine_list}
    return render(request, 'reviews/wine_list.html', context)


def wine_detail(request, wine_id):
    wine = get_object_or_404(Wine, pk=wine_id)
    form = ReviewForm()
    return render(request, 'reviews/wine_detail.html', {'wine': wine, 'form': form})


@login_required
def add_review(request, wine_id):
    wine = get_object_or_404(Wine, pk=wine_id)
    form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
        comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
        user_name = request.user.username
        review = Review()
        review.wine = wine
        review.user_name = user_name
        review.rating = rating
        review.comment = comment
        review.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        review.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('reviews:wine_detail', args=(wine.id,)))

    return render(request, 'reviews/wine_detail.html', {'wine': wine, 'form': form})



def user_review_list(request, username=None):
    if not username:
        username = request.user.username
    latest_review_list = Review.objects.filter(user_name=username).order_by('-pub_date')
    context = {'latest_review_list':latest_review_list, 'username':username}
    return render(request, 'reviews/user_review_list.html', context)


@login_required
def user_recommendation_list(request):
    # get this user reviews
    user_reviews = Review.objects.filter(user_name=request.user.username).prefetch_related('wine')
    # from the reviews, get a set of wine IDs
    user_reviews_wine_ids = set(map(lambda x: x.wine.id, user_reviews))
    # then get a wine list excluding the previous IDs
    wine_list = Wine.objects.exclude(id__in=user_reviews_wine_ids)

    return render(
        request,
        'reviews/user_recommendation_list.html',
        {'username': request.user.username,'wine_list': wine_list}
    )
```

Comment: After poking around the docs for Django's templating ... I'm curious if the problem is simply a missing space on `static'reviews\images\download(1).jpg'` between `static` and `'reviews...`

Comment: the syntax error is resolved but still the image isn't being displayed. Please help

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a space on your static tag, should be

```
{% static 'reviews\images\download(1).jpg' %}
```

Also, it's usually best to keep load tags at the top, right after extends.

If the image is not being loaded check if the image shows by going to the path directly in the browser, if it is not showing, perhaps the issue is in with the STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT settings.